Why "tilling and tending" of Eden are not considered commandments?
"God settled the Human in the garden of Eden, to til it and tend it." That preceded his introduction to its plants and trees and the commandments to withdraw from eating from them.
Was Adam informed of his duty to till and tend it, and, if yes, why aren't those considered his first Mitzvos?

Considered by whom?

@Nahum Our sages/our tradition/commonly etc.

Do you have a source from the sages/tradition

@Nahum I don’t understand what you’re getting at. It is commonly accepted that Adam was only commanded not to eat from the tree and he blew it.

It seems you don't have a source from the sages/tradition. If you're going with the man on the street I would think that the fact that Adam isn't explicity told about it and/or it not being a proscription explains it satisfactorily
